# pairing the data in two seperate strings in Java

Tags: java, string

In this class I have two Strings. I want to pair the ordered int with the planet associated with it. the moons and each planet are in order with each other. Am I pairing them correctly? If not please show me how this would be done.

```
public class Planet {

    int moons;
    String planets;

    Planet(int moons, String planets)
    {
        this.moons = moons;
        this.planets = planets;
    }


    private String planets ( String s ) {       
        String[] planets = {"Mercury moons = ", "Venus moons =  ", "Earth moons = ", "Mars moons = ", "Jupiter moons = ", "Saturn moons = ", "Uranus moons = ", "Neptune moons = ", "Pluto moons = " };
        return s;       
    }


    private int moons ( int i ) {   
        int[] moons = {0, 0, 1, 2, 67, 62, 27, 14, 5};
        return i;
    }


}
```

Comment: Your requirement is not clear!

Comment: Start by removing the part in `<>` characters.  Move those arrays up into the `main` method - they don't belong where you've put them.  And have a good think about what you want those two private methods to do.

Comment: The OO design here feels broken. Why can every Planet tell me the name of "all" planets and how many moons each has?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try this you should do this as such.

```
public class Planet
{

static int[] moons;

static String[] planets;

Planet(int[] moons, String[] planets) {
    this.moons = moons;
    this.planets = planets;
}

private static String[] planets() {
    String[] planets = { "Mercury moons = ", "Venus moons =  ", "Earth moons = ", "Mars moons = ", "Jupiter moons = ", "Saturn moons = ", "Uranus moons = ", "Neptune moons = ", "Pluto moons = " };
    return planets;
}

private static int[] moons() {
    int[] moons = { 0, 0, 1, 2, 67, 62, 27, 14, 5 };
    return moons;
}

private void pairPlanet() {
    if (moons.length == planets.length) {
        for (int i = 0; i < moons.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(planets[i] + moons[i]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

And your Main method goes such that

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Planet planet = new Planet(Planet.moons(), Planet.planets());
    planet.pairPlanet();
}
```